# First N prime numbers optimization

Tags: c, algorithm

I've seen already a certain number of questions related to the argument, but as soon as no one matches perfectly what I am asking for I am making a new one. I have to calculate the first N prime numbers (1000 in the example). I came out with a working algorithm which is working fine but it is not optimized at all.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_NUMBERS 1000
int main()
{
   int prime[MAX_NUMBERS]={0};
   int filled=0;
   prime[filled++]=2;
   int n=0,i=0;
   while(filled<MAX_NUMBERS) {
      for( n=prime[filled-1]+1; ;n++ ) {
         int found =0;
         for( i=0; i<filled && (found==0); i++ ) {
            if( (n%prime[i]) == 0 ) {
               found = 1;
            }
         }
         if( !found ) {
            break;
         }
       }
       /* we know that this always exists */
       prime[filled++]=n;
   }
   for(i=0;i<filled;i++) {
      printf( "prime number %d\n", prime[i] );
   }
   return 0;
```

}

Do someone have an idea how this could be optimised? Is there any algorithmic change that can help in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimized?"

Comment: does it need to be optimized?  Is performance currently a problem?

Comment: Maybe this would be a good candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since the code is currently working.

Comment: @RobertHarvey with optimized I mean reducing the number of loops performed in order to find the next valid prime number as this algorithm has an internal loops that everytime scans for all element of the actual array.

Comment: So it's a performance problem, then?

Comment: @RobertHarvey let's say yes.

Comment: Most easy optimization is to skip all even numbers...

for( n=prime[filled-1]+2; ;n += 2 ) {

Comment: you can use `i<filled/2` instead `i<filled`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to reduce number of loops performed, you can store the table of the small primes in your source code.

Another small optimization is based on the fact that primes greater than 3 are all of the form 6k-1 or 6k+1. So instead of checking three odd numbers out of every six, you would check only two for primality.

However a better way to find primes is to use some kind of sieves as mentioned above:
[Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin), [Sieve of Sundaram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram).

Answer (score 1):

```
int found =0;
         for( i=0; i<filled && (found==0); i++ ) {
            if( (n%prime[i]) == 0 ) {
               found = 1;
            }
         }
         if( !found ) {
            break;
         }
```

Change this to:

```
int found =0;
         for( i=0; i < filled && prime[i]*prime[i]<=n; i++ ) {
            if( (n%prime[i]) == 0 ) {
               found = 1;
               break;
            }
         }
         if( !found ) {
            break;
         }
```

Comment: That's better (you noticed you found 9 or 25?)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do is through sieving method like the following being most easy and very efficient:-

[Sieve of eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: @AbhishekBansal the sieve does it more efficiently than what he has done, at first first it considers every number as prime and cancells out all multiples of primes in each iteration. Just to mention to him how it is done efficiently i gave the link.

Comment: also, [sieve of atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) is  slightly faster (though insignificant for the op's purposes)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your number of loops by doing

```
for( i = 0; prime[i] <= sqrt(n); i++ ) {...}
```

I used `sqrt(filled)` because you do not need to check a number greater than that of its square to know whether it is divisible by any number less than it (excluding `1`) or not. (Do not forget to include ` header)

Comment: @CareyGregory The loop is for iterating through the prime array, not numbers from 1 to sqrt(filled).

Comment: Doh!  Careless comment deleted.

Comment: Though I would prefer i*i to sqrt function and there is a minor typo, prime[i]*prime[i] < n

Comment: @AbhishekBansal; ...and ultimately `prime[i]*prime[i]<n` becomes `prime[i] < sqrt(n)`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes I was just concerned about cost for sqrt computation versus multiplication.